# How to generate class file in php with php variables

Tags: php

I have problem on generating text file "Appconfiguration.php" my code in php write a text file Appconfiguration.php and put the string content in it but unfortunately I get an error. what I want to do is transfer the php variable as string in to the Appconfiguration.php. for example i have the string to transfer as $var1='website_name'; var1 does not transferred in to the generated file which is "Appconfiguration.php" because it says "undefined variable $var1" again i don't want any value of $var1 i just want it to be a string like "$var1" and not be a variable when the file writing process occur.
here's my code.

```
$myfile = fopen("Appconfiguration.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt =
"
<?php
    class AppConfig
    {
        public $var1='".$site_name."';
    }
?>
";
$data=stripslashes($txt);
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```

and this is the generated output
Appconfiguration.php"

```
<?php
  class AppConfig
  {
     public ='mysite.com';
  }
?>
```

this is the error in browser.

Notice: **Undefined variable**: var1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\echo\process\config.php on line 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the variable in your string, otherwise the php interpreter will look for the variable by that name:

```
$myfile = fopen("Appconfiguration.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt =
"
<?php
    class AppConfig
    {
        public \$var1='".$site_name."';
    }
?>
";
$data=stripslashes($txt);
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the single quotes to not recognize variables:

```
$myfile = fopen("Appconfiguration.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt =
'
<?php
    class AppConfig
    {
        public $var1="'.$site_name.'";
    }
?>
';
$data=stripslashes($txt);
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```

Enjoy...